# Help figuring out some for loop logic

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I need some help figuring out this for loop logic. I know exactly what I want to do, but I sadly can't seem to get to it.

This is my code at the moment.

```
<? foreach($ticket_details as $ticket): ?>
  <tr class="tableBG" style="background-color: #fc6">
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['price']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['priceWithinAllocation']; ?></td>
    <? for($i = 0; $i < $event_details['number_of_days']; $i++): ?>
      <? 
      foreach($ticket['days'] as $key => $value)
      {
        if($value == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event_details['startDate'] . "+ $i day")))
        {
          echo "<td>&#10003;</td>";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<td>--</td>";
        } 
      }
      ?>
    <? endfor; ?>
    <td align='center'>
      <input type='button' class='remove' id='remove[ticket][<?= $ticket['ticketID'] ?>]'  value='REMOVE' />
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This doesn't really work.

My tickets array looks like this:

```
    [5] => Array
    (
        [ticketID] => 5
        [eventID] => 1
        [name] => Thu
        [price] => 500
        [priceWithinAllocation] => 250
        [day] => 2011-08-25
        [days] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-08-25
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [ticketID] => 6
        [eventID] => 1
        [name] => Wed+Thu
        [price] => 900
        [priceWithinAllocation] => 110
        [day] => 2011-08-24
        [days] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-08-24
                [1] => 2011-08-25
            )

    )
```

When `$ticket['days']` contains more than one value, it prints out too many empty (--) `<td>`. I'm not sure how to do the loop without having it print more than I need. Here's a screenshot of what happens with this code:
[image: this makes me cry]

I tried some stuff with `if(count($ticket['days'])) { }` but that didn't work out. So now I'm stuck.

I realise this is a fairly vague question because I didn't provide too much code here; if needed, I can provide more, but there's a lot of stuff going on so I kept it to a minimum.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `echo "<td>$i--$key</td>";` and look at the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print a cell for each date in $ticket['days']. That's why you get too much cells.

Try this :

```
<? foreach($ticket_details as $ticket): ?>
  <tr class="tableBG" style="background-color: #fc6">
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['price']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?= $ticket['priceWithinAllocation']; ?></td>
    <? for($i = 0; $i < $event_details['number_of_days']; $i++): ?>
      <? 
      $foundDate = false;
      foreach($ticket['days'] as $key => $value)
      {
        if($value == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event_details['startDate'] . "+ $i day")))
        {
          $foundDate = true;
        }
      }
      if($foundDate)
      {
        echo "<td>&#10003;</td>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<td>--</td>";
      } 
      ?>
    <? endfor; ?>
    <td align='center'>
      <input type='button' class='remove' id='remove[ticket][<?= $ticket['ticketID'] ?>]'  value='REMOVE' />
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You're a hero. Thanks a lot. I never wouldve thought of doing it like that; learn something everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a loop inside a loop inside a loop:

this bit:

```
<? for($i = 0; $i < $event_details['number_of_days']; $i++): ?>
  <?  foreach($ticket['days'] as $key => $value)
```

causing you the problem.

for each day out of ['number_of_days'], which is lets say X, then for each ['days'] which is lets say Y, will give you X*Y.

some tickets have 1 day in ['days'], others have 2 days in ['days']. thats which some will show twice as many columns as others.

for ticket 5 you have 1 day, so it shows X columns.

for ticket 6 you have 2 days, so it shows 2X columns

Comment: Thanks. That explains why it went all weird ;D